# In order : launch new terminal, launch R environment in the new terminal, execute commands in R environment

Tags: r, sh, gnome-terminal

I would like a shell script that launches a new terminal, opens the R environment in the terminal and executes commands in the R environment of the new terminal.
Here's what I did which is not working :

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in $(seq 25)
do
gnome-terminal -x sh "R; source('source.r'); function($i)"
done
```

Where, **function()** is an r function in the file **"source.r"**

Please help.

**N.B.** I don't want to launch the program using the command **"Rscript"**

**EDIT 1 :** I don't want to use the command Rscript because the execution halts after sometime (don't know why). In an R environment the script works fine though. Here's what I tried with the command Rscript :

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in $(seq 25)
do
gnome-terminal -e "Rscript script.r $i"
done
```

**EDIT 2 :** I found the reason why the script execution halted with the command Rscript. It was a bug in the code. Now I can make things work with what I did in **EDIT 1**. Would be nice to know if things can be made to work by not using Rscript i.e. launching R in different terminals and executing commands in each terminal from the shell script.

Comment: Why don't you use an Rscript with `#!Path2/Rscript` directly?

Comment: I need to launch the Rscript on separate terminals. In each terminal the Rscript runs with a separate parameter (the value of "i"). I have tried launching the script in different terminals using the command "Rscript" (see EDIT 1) but the execution halts after some time. The script runs fine in an R environment though.

Comment: As I am on windows, I fear I can't really help. I am not sure, but perhaps there is a limitation to the maximum number of terminals/connections which causes the halting after reaching this maximum?