# gnome-terminal execute multiple R commands by invoking R environment

Tags: r, unix

I would like a shell script that launches a new terminal, opens the R environment in the terminal and executes commands in the R environment of the new terminal.

I found a similar Q in the below link,

[In order : launch new terminal, launch R environment in the new terminal, execute commands in R environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37434795/in-order-launch-new-terminal-launch-r-environment-in-the-new-terminal-execut)

But the solution discussed in the thread (Rscript) doesn't work for me.

I'm trying to run the below code,

```
gnome-terminal -- /bin/sh -c 'R;Sys.getenv("PATH")'
```

But I'm getting an error when I use (Sys.getenv("PATH")) after R command. I guess it is due to /bin/sh.

```
gnome-terminal -- /bin/sh -c 'R'
```

When I run the above code, it opens another terminal and invokes R environment successfully.

Can someone advise how to execute multiple R commands in gnome-terminal.

Comment: have you tried to use **tmux**? it's a unix software that allows you to run multiple terminals in background. it's also very useful to run codes through **ssh**.

Comment: I just need to use gnome-terminal only in this instance and not often